# How do I specifically target internet explorer with htaccess deflate

Tags: internet-explorer, .htaccess, deflate

This is closely related to anothewr question I have asked but since this is quite specific I thought it would be better asked seperately.

I have a very simple test site which consists of three files, index.html, all.js and .htaccess, here is my .htaccess:

```
# Compress some text file types
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/xml application/xml application/xhtml+xml text/javascript text/css application/x-javascript application/javascript application/json
```

This is the only thing I am doing to compress the files - I havent added any headers.
Now I realise this has a lot of mime types I dont need but I think we have everything covered here. However for some reason files are only being compressed in firefox, not IE. Furthermore, if I look at the site through firefox and use user agent swither to switch to an IE user agent compression stops immediately.

I need this working in IE, My broader question is how do I make this happen but I am thinking it may be due to some Browser matching in the config so I am wondering how I can specifically target IE with deflate in htaccess.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Off topic. You are missing the image/x-icon mime, for compressing the favicon (if you have any). The problem itself seems like a wrong configuration on the host side. IE6 before SP1 had some trouble with compressed content, so I think the host just disabled compression for all IE.

Comment: This is a test system with no favicon, but I may not have done this on the main site as I was under the impression you couldnt use gzip/deflate on image files - is this incorrect.

Comment: Most image formats are already compressed, like jpeg and png, so gzipping those would be counterproductive. The .ico format like the bmp format is uncompressed/raw pixel data, and can therefore be compressed significantly using gzip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at your hosts config: `grep -Ri BrowserMatch /etc/httpd /etc/apache2`  You can do this from PHP with a system() call.  It may be that your host has specified the rules too tightly.  See also [Special Purpose Environment Variables](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/env.html#special), and a number of blog posts one this.

Comment: I am on a shared hosting plan and when I run system(); I get a list of hosted sites and not a lot more. Because I am on shared hosting I do not have access to the full file system, my root directory contains .bashrc .bash_logout .bash_profile logs & the public_html directory. I have contacted my hosting provider and was told ...there are no issues with gzip/deflate on our servers... As you are having issues with Internet Explorer I recommend adding code to work around this .... we do not provide support for coding...

Answer (score 0):

It appears from log files and studying network traffic that the files are actually being compressed but IE is reporting this incorrectly.